# cmake building multiple projects as libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, vulkan

I am trying to build two projects as libraries and one executable that depends on them.

I have a vulkan library cmake file that make successfully works if I call it individually.
Under renderer/gfxVk

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(project_name gfxVk)
project(${project_name})
set(HAVE_LIBC TRUE)

set(TARGET_ARCHITECTURE "x64")

set(src
    gfxDevice.cpp
)

set(headers

)

add_library(${project_name} ${src} ${headers})

find_package(Vulkan)

if(Vulkan_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(${project_name} PUBLIC Vulkan::Vulkan})
    target_link_libraries(${project_name} Vulkan::Vulkan)
endif()
```

And have an application project that will actually be executable.
Under application

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(project_name application)
project(${project_name})
set(HAVE_LIBC TRUE)

set(TARGET_ARCHITECTURE "x64")

set(src
    application.cpp
)

set(headers

)

add_executable(${project_name} ${src} ${headers})
```

Finally, I have a cmake file at the root directory:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# cmake config
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_SOURCE_CHANGES ON)
set(CMAKE_DISABLE_IN_SOURCE_BUILD ON)

# project config
set(project_name Engine)
project(${project_name})

set(TARGET_ARCHITECTURE "x64")

set(HAVE_LIBC TRUE)

set(src
    application/application.cpp
)


set(headers

)


add_executable(${project_name} ${src} ${headers})

add_subdirectory(renderer/gfxVk)
add_subdirectory(application)

set_property(DIRECTORY $(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR) PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT application)
```

But this doesn't work. Not sure I got the library and executable set up correctly. Both of individual cmakes does build, but when I try to build it with the last one it fails. Even if it succeeds, not sure this is the right setup.

Comment: `set(project_name gfxVk)` - there is already a variable named literally `PROJECT_NAME` set by `project()` call... `two projects as libraries and one executable that depends on the` - so, firstly, your project has two `add_executable` executables and one library. And, if you want to link executable with a library.. do you know what `target_link_libraries` does?

Comment: "when I try to build it with the last one it fails." - How does it fail? Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message** you got.